# Get key value pair result of activities in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Get key value pair result of activities. get all activities under first elements term as key.

**INPUT**

```
[
 {
   "_id": "diamond",
   "activities": [
     [
       {
         "term": "11",
         "sport_name": "football"
       }
     ]
   ]
 },
 {
   "_id": "topaz",
   "activities": [
     [
       {
         "term": "12",
         "sport_name": "football"
       }
     ],
     [
       {
         "term": "11",
         "sport_name": "football"
       },
       {
         "term": "11",
         "sport_name": "hand ball"
       }
     ]
   ]
 }
]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
 {
   "_id": "diamond",
   "activities": [
       {
           "11": [
               {
                   "term": "11",
                   "sport_name": "football"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
 },
 {
   "_id": "topaz",
   "activities": [
       {
           "12": [
               {
                 "term": "12",
                 "sport_name": "football"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "11": [
               {
                 "term": "11",
                 "sport_name": "football"
               },
               {
                 "term": "11",
                 "sport_name": "hand ball"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "activities": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$activities",
          "in": {
            "k": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$this.term", 0] },
            "v": "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yRa1GEqCj_G)